# Getting an error saying "No such file or directory" when using 'put' command in Hadoop

Tags: linux, hadoop

Hadoop rejects my attempt to add a text file to the HDFS filesystem with the error message "No such file or directory." I've also tried adding files of different formats as well but still the same result.

[screenshot of the error I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RNFjH.png)

What am I doing wrong here? Is it my code?

```
hdfs dfs -put /home/srikanthamsa/hello.txt /
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current user is `hdoop`, which most likely doesn't have access to read files from `/home/srikanthamsa`

Your error has nothing to do with HDFS. For example, you should get the same error from `cat /home/srikanthamsa/hello.txt`

Perhaps you should create a file at `/home/hdoop` and try to put that instead?

Or `sudo su - srikanthamsa` first